# Java removing double dash but not single dash

Tags: java, parsing

I am parsing numerical data and sometimes I get negative numbers and when nothing is available I get `--`

I created a class to clean the numbers and passed them through a command:

```
output = output.replaceAll("\\-", " ");
```

I thought it was working fine because the double dashs were gone but now I realized all my negative numbers appear to be positive.  I'm not sure how to approach it, is there a way to specifically say if two dashes exist after each other to replace it? or is there a way to accept a dash only if its followed by a number?

please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Personnaly i would just parse the numbers with the standard JAVA API with the relevant pattern and interpret the parse errors as no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just replace the "--" so negative numbers will not get affected ?

```
output = output.replaceAll("\\-\\-", " ");
```

or just

```
output = output.replace("--", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the regular expression with double dashes:

```
output = output.replaceAll("\\-\\-", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) may be an easier way to parse the input. Scanner accepts a variety of different sequences (String, File, PrintStream (like System.in), and other types I believe) and will help you parse through the provided sequence easily.

In your case, a Scanner will let you obtain numeric values easily using the [nextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method:

```
String fileName = "sample.txt";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt())
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    else
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

You could use this and then construct the data that are just Strings and separate them from what values are actual numbers. This could be a little more easier to use in the long run.

My reason for posting this is to point out that there may be other ways to parse through the data. It may not be exactly what you need right at this moment, but it could come in handy in the future. It may be a viable option when/if you reconsider refactoring this code. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`output = output.replaceAll("--", " ");` 
or 
`output=output.replaceAll("-{2}");`

Either will work, as evidenced by the clojure code from the REPL. (it uses java string handling).

> user=> (re-seq #"--" negdata) ("--")
>   user=> (re-seq #"-{2}" negdata) ("--")
>   user=> (println negdata)
>   --2.0 nil user=> ( println posdata)
>   -1.0 nil